# Cookies with Jsoup

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I'm having issues with sending POST data to this site:

```
https://www.amazon.com/ap/signin?openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.assoc_handle=amzn_mturk_worker&openid.ns.pape=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fextensions%2Fpape%2F1.0&_encoding=UTF8&openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.pape.max_auth_age=43200&marketplaceId=A384XSLT9ODACQ&clientContext=703ea210dfe6fd07defd5ab30ac8d9&openid.return_to=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mturk.com%2Fmturk%2Fendsignin`
```

I'm using Jsoup. I'm trying to use the same cookies "session-id" for the get data but i'm still not logged in. This is my code:

```
Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect("https://www.amazon.com/ap/signin?openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.assoc_handle=amzn_mturk_worker&openid.ns.pape=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fextensions%2Fpape%2F1.0&_encoding=UTF8&openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.pape.max_auth_age=43200&marketplaceId=A384XSLT9ODACQ&clientContext=703ea210dfe6fd07defd5ab30ac8d9&openid.return_to=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mturk.com%2Fmturk%2Fendsignin").data("email", "blah@gmail.com", "password", "blah").method(Connection.Method.POST).execute();
Document doc2 = res.parse();
sessionId = res.cookie("session-id"); 

Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.mturk.com/mturk/searchbar?selectedSearchType=hitgroups&minReward=0.00&sortType=LastUpdatedTime%3A1&pageSize=50").cookie("SESSIONID", sessionId).get();
```

Where e-mail and password are real information instead of "blah". I don't know if my issue is how I parse the cookie or send the POST data originally.

Edit: So the site uses OpenID. Not sure if I should make a whole new question, but how would I go about it now? I basically need to login and pull information off the site after login. Here is my post info:

```
appActionToken:pj2FxGfwLZT6nheliE7BMxwZrTUKEj3D
appAction:SIGNIN
clientContext:ape:NzAzZWEyMTBkZmU2ZmQwN2RlZmQ1YWIzMGFjOGQ5
openid.pape.max_auth_age:ape:NDMyMDA=
openid.return_to:ape:aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cubXR1cmsuY29tL210dXJrL2VuZHNpZ25pbg==
prevRID:ape:S1kyUFNDUkhLVFZSSjRGMjBYUUo=
openid.identity:ape:aHR0cDovL3NwZWNzLm9wZW5pZC5uZXQvYXV0aC8yLjAvaWRlbnRpZmllcl9zZWxlY3Q=
openid.assoc_handle:ape:YW16bl9tdHVya193b3JrZXI=
openid.mode:ape:Y2hlY2tpZF9zZXR1cA==
openid.ns.pape:ape:aHR0cDovL3NwZWNzLm9wZW5pZC5uZXQvZXh0ZW5zaW9ucy9wYXBlLzEuMA==
openid.claimed_id:ape:aHR0cDovL3NwZWNzLm9wZW5pZC5uZXQvYXV0aC8yLjAvaWRlbnRpZmllcl9zZWxlY3Q=
pageId:ape:YW16bl9tdHVya193b3JrZXI=
openid.ns:ape:aHR0cDovL3NwZWNzLm9wZW5pZC5uZXQvYXV0aC8yLjA=
email: -Deleted-
create:0
password: -Deleted-
metadata1: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`
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? If so, please post it.

Comment: There is no error. It just doesn't post anything.

Answer (score 0):

The site you're trying to log in make use of Javascript. Since Jsoup doesn't support Javascript (Jsoup 1.8.3 as of this writing), I advice you to use some better approaches: [ui4j](https://github.com/ui4j/ui4j) or [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org). The choice is yours.

Comment: I'm trying to do that now. I'm having a hard time figuring out the required info for this login. I have ap_email and ap_password. Is there something i'm missing to submit?

Comment: @user2053310 I can't tell what you're missing. Many details can be hidden. As TDG stated, use the developer tools to get all those details , espacially requests and cookies then use `FormElement` for not missing any POST parameters.

Comment: The site is using openid. Do you know if FormElement will help with this?

Comment: @user2053310 FormElemnt won't help with this. See my update.